# Swift 3 - Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'MyStruct' operands

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering

I have a custom struct...

```
struct MyStruct {

    let viewController: UIViewController
    let view:UIView

    init(viewController:UIViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }
}
```

I have an array of them, and then I want to check if this array contains a specific struct...

```
let aStruct = someStruct
if structArray.filter { $0 == aStruct } {
   print("do stuff")
}
```

but I'm getting the error *Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'MyStruct' operands* ... first, why can't I filter structs in this way... second how should I search the array if not this way...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you `struct` conform to the `Equatable` protocol.

Comment: Note that even once you've conformed `MyStruct` to `Equatable`, you can't say `if structArray.filter { $0 == aStruct } {...}` – use `contains(_:)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the struct to conform to the `Equatable` protocol to allow it to determine what is considered 'equal'.

Assuming you consider them equal if they have the same `viewController` property, you could do something like this:

```
extension MyStruct: Equatable{}

func ==(lhs: MyStruct, rhs: MyStruct) -> Bool {
    return lhs.viewController == rhs.viewController;
}
```